# Unnecessary update by Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an entity, for example Manager and some json field, that contains some list of clients.

```
@Entity
@TypeDefs({@TypeDef( name = "json", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class )})
public class Manager {

  @Id
  private String managerId;

  @Type( type = "json" ) 
  @Column( columnDefinition = "jsonb", name = "json" )
  private SomeJsonDto json;

  ... 
}
```

Also, i have custom class Context, where I got some entities from DB via JpaRepository and map them to the Map.

```
public class Context{
  private Map<String, Manager> managersFromDBMap;
}
```

After that, I need to create new Manager if not exists and add some client to the list of clients.

First step, I create new Manager, make em.persist(em annotated with PersistanceContext) and put that object in my managersFromDBMap in Context.

Second step, I get that manager from managersFromDBMap and add some clients to the list.

All these steps I do in @Transactional method and expect that at the end of transaction I will flush changes and get only 1 insert into DB(new manager with clients). But I see 1 insert(for create manager) and 1 update(for update that manager with clients)

```
Hibernate: insert into manager ...
Hibernate: update manager ...
```

I don't understand why hibernate makes 2 requests to DB if all my changes were made with 1 entity in 1 transaction. Am I doing something wrong or hibernate will always make 2 requests?

Comment: Dunno but transactions are not optimizations.

Comment: Do you have any parent-child relation on the manager? If so, take a look at this (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html)